# Pruning Blockchain and creating multi wallets

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, pruning, wallet-import

I am trying to determine if I could use pruning blockchain option on my future bitcoin node or not.

I will create a multiple wallets by RPC calls and I need to be able to check the history of transactions for each wallets, even if a wallet has been created 1 years ago for which the transactions blocks are no more present on the node due to pruning.

Do you know if it is possible to continue to check transactions of a generated wallet for transactions blocks who are no more kept ?

Answer (score 1):

No, Bitcoin Core needs to rescan the blockchain from the time the wallet was created to recover its transaction history. If the birthday of the wallet is older than the blocks you retain due to pruning, Bitcoin Core will fall back to repeating the initial synchronization and download all blocks from scratch.